# Implement metadata on folders only, not documents

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

I'd like to set up metadata in a document library so that it's only applicable to folders (and subfolders). Meaning that when we add documents they shouldn't get the metadata from the columns on the folders.

I am not experienced in Sharepoint, but I tried with lists and played around with a new document library but had no success.

I thought maybe [DocumentSets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-document-sets-3dbcd93e-0bed-46b7-b1ba-b31de2bcd234) may help but it seems I don't have enough privileges to create them (if that's really the solution here).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Folder content type(called CustomeFolder in my test), and add site columns based on your requirement.

Then go to the library that you want to use, enable content type management, and add the custom folder content type into your library.
After that, click "customFolder" to create a folder/subfolder with metadata:
[image]

How to create a custom content type:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-customize-a-site-content-type-27eb6551-9867-4201-a819-620c5658a60f
How to add a content type into a library:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60
Note: To create a custom content type, you need to have site owner permission.

Document Set also is a choice, but to create a document set, you need to be a site collection administrator.

Create and Configure a new Document set:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-configure-a-new-document-set-content-type-9db6d6dc-c23a-4dcd-a359-3e4bbbc47fc1
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-document-set-in-sharepoint-online-office-365/

Comment: We actually got admin rights and managed to do that with the custom contentTypes. I was going to write a response and you beat me to it. Thank you for your elaborate response!